# Convert Weekly Total to Daily Average

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I have a table of forecasts like so:

```
Item      ForecastDate     ForecastQty
A123      7/30/17          140
A123      8/6/17           70
A123      8/13/17          70
A123      8/20/17          70
A123      8/27/17          70
A123      9/3/17           45
```

I need to come up with a daily average across all days (including weekends), so my output would look something like:

```
Item      ForecastDate     DailyFcstQty
A123      7/30/17          20
A123      7/31/17          20
A123      8/1/17           20
A123      8/2/17           20
A123      8/3/17           20
A123      8/4/17           20
A123      8/5/17           20
A123      8/6/17           20
A123      8/7/17           10
A123      8/8/17           10
```

and so on.

How do can I convert this weekly data (always a Sunday if that matters) into a daily average across the days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Dates Table, which can be done with a CTE. Then, full join to that to enumerate your dates... and do the division. Since you stated the date in your data is always on a Sunday, the divisor of 7 is static, as is the `dateadd(day,6,t.ForecastDate)`.

```
declare @table table (Item varchar(4), ForecastDate date, ForecastQty int)
insert into @table
values
('A123','7/30/17',140),
('A123','8/6/17',70),
('A123','8/13/17',70),
('A123','8/20/17',70),
('A123','8/27/17',70),
('A123','9/3/17',45)

declare @minDate date = (select min(ForecastDate) from @table)
declare @maxDate date = (select max(ForecastDate) from @table)
;with GetDates As  
(  
select @minDate as TheDate              --startdate
from @table
UNION ALL  
select DATEADD(day,1, TheDate) from GetDates  
where TheDate <= @maxDate   --maxdate
)

select distinct * 
into #tempDates 
from GetDates 
option(maxrecursion 0)

select * from #tempDates order by TheDate
select 
    t.Item
    ,d.TheDate
    ,DailyFcstQty = t.ForecastQty / 7
from @table t
full outer join
    #tempDates d on 
    d.TheDate >= t.ForecastDate
    and d.TheDate <= dateadd(day,6,t.ForecastDate)
order by
    t.ForecastDate


drop table #tempDates
```

**RETURNS**

```
+------+------------+--------------+
| Item |  TheDate   | DailyFcstQty |
+------+------------+--------------+
| A123 | 2017-07-30 |           20 |
| A123 | 2017-07-31 |           20 |
| A123 | 2017-08-01 |           20 |
| A123 | 2017-08-02 |           20 |
| A123 | 2017-08-03 |           20 |
| A123 | 2017-08-04 |           20 |
| A123 | 2017-08-05 |           20 |
| A123 | 2017-08-06 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-07 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-08 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-09 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-10 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-11 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-12 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-13 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-14 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-15 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-16 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-17 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-18 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-19 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-20 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-21 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-22 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-23 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-24 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-25 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-26 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-27 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-28 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-29 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-30 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-08-31 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-09-01 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-09-02 |           10 |
| A123 | 2017-09-03 |            6 |
| A123 | 2017-09-04 |            6 |
+------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: This is great.  I was able to get your code to return results after commenting out the: 'select * from #tempDates order by TheDate' near the middle of the statement.  I'm still having issues getting it adapted from my general example to my specific dataset, but that's on me.  Thank you!

Comment: And now I've got it rocking my data, thanks @scsimon!